# Can "bring" be used in both the "to-here sense" and "to-there sense"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I know you can use it like this (in the *to-here sense*):

> "Please bring me the bottle." (To here.)

Can it be used in the *to-there sense*?

Example:

> As he was driving, he thought of bringing something else to the party.
> (To there.)

Comment: Yep.  Both sentences make sense here.  The first is like saying "Bring the bottle (to me)." and the second is like saying "I thought of bringing the bottle (with me)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring can mean either:

> to take or carry someone or something to a place or a person

*"Shall I bring anything to the party?" "Oh, just a bottle."*

or

> in the direction of the person speaking

*When they visit us they always bring their dog with them.*

[Bring (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bring)